# Problema en Python [SE REPITE Y NO DA EL NOMBRE DEL DETALLE]

Tags: python

[image]

Tengo un problema en Python el cual es el de arriba, les comento de que se trata el programa, el Usuario ingresa Una palabra en este caso "MERCADO" y le da un valor de "10000" se repite en la siguiente, pero al monstrar ya el detalle se repide dos 0 intermedio de los dos y no muestra el nombre [VER IMAGEN CUADRO ROJO], desde hace 1 semana tengo este problema y no he podido solucionar, necesito la ayuda para poder solucionar esto, se les agradec.

El codigo es:

```
arregloDeGastos = []
gastos = []
sumaTotal = 0
nombreGasto = {}
salir = ("")
variable = 0


def detalles():
    sumaTotal = 0
    for i in range(len(arregloDeGastos)):
        print("Sus gastos en detalle fueron:" , arregloDeGastos[i])
        sumaTotal += arregloDeGastos[i]     
    print("Sus gastos totales fueron: ", sumaTotal)
    print()
    salario = int(input("Ingresa tu salario: "))
    sumaTotal = salario - sumaTotal
    print("Lo que te queda libre es,", sumaTotal,"Recuerda ahorrar.")
    return sumaTotal

while salir != "salir":
    print()
    salir = input("DALE ENTER PARA CONTINUAR, DE LO CONTRARIO salir: ")
    if(salir != "salir"):
        arregloDeGastos.append(int(variable))
        nombre = input("Digite el nombre del gasto: ")

        for j in range(1):
            print("Digite el valor del gasto",nombre,": ")
            gasto = int(input())
            arregloDeGastos.append(gasto)
            nombreGasto[nombre] = gastos

        gastos = []

        sumaTotal = 0

detalles()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estas agregando a tu arreglo el valor 0 cuando el usuario presiona enter.  En otras palabras estas agregando dos veces.  La forma correcta seria agregar solo una vez despues que el usuario ingresa el gasto asi:

```
while salir != "salir":
    print()
    salir = input("DALE ENTER PARA CONTINUAR, DE LO CONTRARIO salir: ")
    if(salir != "salir"):        
        nombre = input("Digite el nombre del gasto: ")

        for j in range(1):
            print("Digite el valor del gasto",nombre,": ")
            gasto = int(input())
            arregloDeGastos.append(gasto)
            nombreGasto[nombre] = gastos

        gastos = []

        sumaTotal = 0
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, de alguna u otra forma sabes como añadir el nombre del Diccionario o el nombre de la variable en los detalles en este caso añadir Mercado Y Sandias en detalles: Ejemblo: El Mercado en detalle : 10000
El Sandias en detalle: 5000

Comment: El objeto `nombreGasto` lo puedes volver en array y despues que el usuario ingresa el nombre hacer un `nombreGasto.append(nombre)`.  Luego en tu for loop en tu funcion detalles, desplegarias el indice correcto de ese array

Comment: No se manejar aun el for loop y el array, voy a buscar.